# Show listview depending on condition

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

i have a customadapter that right now is showing correctly all my contacts. i am also checking some conditions in a jsonobject to display some images in the listview. this works fine.

now i want to achieve that instead of displaying one or another image, the whole row is displayed or not displayed.

the part that determines the condition is the following

```
JSONObject c;
                try {
                    c = android.getJSONObject(position);
                    error = c.getString(TAG_ERROR);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 0) {contactViewHolder.imgTiene
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);}
                    if(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 1) {contactViewHolder.imgTiene
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);}
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

so if the result is 1 i dont want the row to be displayed.

the code for the listview is the following

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    // View MyView = convertView;

    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        // Inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = li.inflate(
                R.layout.contactos_list_item, null);

        contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder();

        contactViewHolder.imgContact = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.flag);
        contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtView_name);
        contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtview_number);
        //contactViewHolder.txtViewError = (TextView) convertView
          //      .findViewById(R.id.txtview_check);
        contactViewHolder.imgTiene = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.flag2);

        convertView.setTag(contactViewHolder);
    } else {
        contactViewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        cur.moveToPosition(position);

        name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if (name != null)
            contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName.setText(name);
        else
            contactViewHolder.txtViewContactName.setText("Unknown");


        // Add Phone Number //

        String phoneNumber = cur
                .getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        if (phoneNumber != null)
            contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
        else
            contactViewHolder.txtViewPhoneNumber.setText("Unknown");

        Uri uri = getPhotoUri(Long.parseLong(fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)));


        if (uri != null) {
            contactViewHolder.imgContact.setImageURI(uri);
            if (contactViewHolder.imgContact.getDrawable() == null){contactViewHolder.imgContact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_person);}
        } else {
            contactViewHolder.imgContact
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_person);
        }

        JSONObject c;
        try {
            c = android.getJSONObject(position);
            error = c.getString(TAG_ERROR);
            if(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 0) {contactViewHolder.imgTiene
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);}
            if(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 1) {contactViewHolder.imgTiene
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);}
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //contactViewHolder.txtViewError.setText(error);


    return convertView;
}
```

How should can i condition what is returned?
i tried using a boolean and setting and if() to return convertView but it did not allow it.

Searching further i have found that you can change the inflate

```
if(condition)
{
  convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_null,null);
  return convertView;
}
else
{
   convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_content,null);
   return convertView;
}
```

Where should i put this if()?

thanks all for helping

Comment: Just did anther attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might Work

Create a `null_item` in Layout folder and return it though inlfate as in

```
if((Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 1)
{
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.null_item, null);
}
return convertView;
```

**null_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i added convertView.setVisibility((Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ERROR)) == 1) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); in the try() and now i get empty rows, how can i make them not displayed at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better method. Had to test it myself wasn't sure if itd work or not but after seeing as we can make it invisible I figured this should work.

```
  if (result == 1) {
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.height = 0;
       convertView.setLayoutParams(params);  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @ashley-alvarado i do not need them in cur. how do i remove them? can you write an if() please. i have a boolean "a" set to true and false. something like     if(a){
     // do not remove
    } else {
     // remove
    }